# In my nginx config $http_origin is empty string

Tags: nginx, access-control

I even tried something stupid like:

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "http://loca${http_origin}lhost:3000";`

and the results is just http://localhost:3000, so it's empty. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think browser will send a request with a header called "Origin". So your nginx can't get $http_origin

`$http_origin` mean "Get request's header: Origin"

You can try this:

```
curl localhost:3000 -H "origin: google.com"
```

`$http_xxx` variables are request's headers

ref: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_

Comment: Thanks for the theory, but why is origin then empty for me?

Comment: We are using axios on client side

Comment: I don't think browser will send a request with a header called "Origin". So your nginx can't get `$http_origin`